# Rails API 404 Error - Deployed with Capistrano, Nginx and Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx

I have created a Rails API Project, and it works locally. (If I browse to `localhost:3000/api/first` it prints `true` on the browser.

I have followed the steps here - https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/14.04 and have deployed the API on my EC2 Ubuntu Server.

If my IP address is - 1.2.3.4, if I browse to `http://1.2.3.4/` I get the Welcome to Nginx message. However if I browse to `http://1.2.3.4/api/first` I get a 404 error.

Here is my **/etc/nginx/sites-available/default**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

    server_name "";
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env    production;
    root         /home/ubuntu/rails/current/public;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
}
```

If I create a folder called `api` (in `/home/ubuntu/rails/current/public`) and, inside it, a text file called `first`, then it shows me the contents of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Install ngnix passenger module and add path to ngnix conf file.

Code should be somthing like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name "";

    # Tell Nginx and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
    root /var/www/app_name/public;

    # Turn on Passenger
    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_ruby /root/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/wrappers/ruby;
}
```

Comment: the `root` should point to the `public` folder of the current release i.e for your case `/var/www/app_name/current/public`, because there may be multiple release folders there, so we explicitly need to point to the current release. [Ref](https://gorails.com/forum/404-not-found-after-deploy-to-ubuntu-server)